# Assign a value to an optional argument passed by reference

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

I just need someone to confirm that the following code is perfectly valid, especially when the optional argument is not given while calling the function. Indeed, in this case I would have expected an exception because the function tries to assign a variable which is not given as an argument.

```
<?php

function myfunc($msg, &$to_assign=null)
{
    echo "$msg\n";
    $to_assign = 78;
}

myfunc('hello'); // <== Is it valid to assign 78 to nothing?
myfunc('world', $v);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php#68835

Comment: And you didn't assign 78 to nothing, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP variables are made of two pieces: the name and the value.

The statement

```
$v = 'abc';
```

generates data structures like this:

```
    +-----------+           +-------+
    | v         | --------> | 'abc' |
    +-----------+           +-------+
```

`v` is the name, `'abc'` is the value.

Assigning a variable by reference produces a new name for the content of an existing variable. The assignment:

```
$to_assign = &$v;
```

produces:

```
    +-----------+
    | v         | -----+
    +-----------+      |    +-------+
                       +--> | 'abc' |  
    +-----------+      |    +-------+
    | to_assign | -----+
    +-----------+
```

Something similar happens when `$to_assign` is the argument (passed by reference) of function `myfunc()`. The only difference is that the name of `$to_assign` is stored in a different place than the name of `$v` and it (the name) is destroyed when the function returns.

#### myfunc('world', $v)

This is how the data structures look like during the execution of `myfunc('world', $v)`:

```
    +-----------+
    | v         | -----------+
    +-----------+            |    +-------+
                             |--> | 'abc' |  
.== myfunc('world', $v) ==.  |    +-------+
|   +-----------+         |  |
|   | to_assign | ----------+
|   +-----------+         |
|   +-----------+         |       +---------+
|   | msg       | --------------> | 'world' |
|   +-----------+         |       +---------+
+=========================+
```

The statement `$to_assign = 78;` replaces the value `'abc'` with `78` and now the value of `$v` is `78`. When the function returns, the (name) of the local variable `$to_assign` is destroyed but its value (now `78`) is still referenced by the name of `$v`; that's why it is not destroyed. After the call `myfunc('world', $v)`, the value of `$v` is `78`.

#### myfunc('hello')

When the function is invoked with a single argument, the default value of `$to_assign` is used to initialize it.

This is how the data structures look like during the call of `myfunc('hello')`

```
    +-----------+                 +-------+
    | v         | --------------> | 'abc' |  
    +-----------+                 +-------+

.==== myfunc('hello') ====.   
|   +-----------+         |       +------+
|   | to_assign | --------------> | NULL |
|   +-----------+         |       +------+
|   +-----------+         |       +---------+
|   | msg       | --------------> | 'hello' |
|   +-----------+         |       +---------+
+=========================+
```

The variable `$to_assign` is now a regular local variable of function `myfunc()`. The statement `$to_assign = 78;` replaces the value `NULL` with `78`. When the function returns the name of the variable `$to_assign` is destroyed and, because it's value (now `78`) becomes orphan (it is not referenced by other name) it is also destroyed. The value of `$v` is not affected.

Comment: Very nice and complete answer, thank you! It can't be clearer

Answer (score -1):

If you want 78 to be your default value then it's best to do it like this:

```
function myfunc($msg, $to_assign=78)
{
    echo "$msg\n";
    echo $to_assign;
}
```

myfunc('hello'); will echo 'hello', 78

myfunc('world',10); will echo 'world', 10

Comment: I don't want a predefined default value, I just need to know if my code is a valid and usable code. `78` is an example but it may be a value computed inside the func

Comment: The change you suggested doesn't preserve the behaviour of the original `myfunc()` function.

Answer (score -1):

For further debugging you can modify your function as:

```
function myfunc($msg, &$to_assign=null)
{
    var_dump(get_defined_vars());
    echo "$msg\n";
    $to_assign = 78;
}
```

First, call

```
myfunc('hello');
```

shows you that there's `$to_assign` variable and it is not a **reference**. So changing it's value will affect **nothing**.

Second, in case of

```
myfunc('world', $v);
```

you can see that `$to_assign` among vars is a **reference** and everyhting works as you expect: value of `$v` is changed to `78`.

So, in both cases you have `$to_assign` variable, but it is either a reference or not. And yes, thanks to @axiac, no local variables are created.